# Get_Template_Part section isn't showing CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, parent-child, footer

I had an HTML landing page that I wanted to integrate with WordPress. I did so by creating the HTML page as a template page with its own header and footer template parts in a child theme of the WordPress theme. However, the header and footers now don't align between the HTML page and other pages.

Getting the WordPress header/footer into the HTML page worked fine enough, but I decided I preferred the HTML page header/footer and want to instead use that one like the WordPress header/footer throughout the rest of the site. To do this I commented out the footer code of the child theme calling out the template directory of the parent themes footer.php and added code to pull the footer from the HTML page template part footer:

```
/** if ( 'landing-page.php' !== basename( get_page_template() ) ) {
    require_once( get_template_directory() . '/footer.php' );
} */ ?>

<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/footer' ); ?>
```

However, I can't get this to work, as the footer shows up without the CSS of the HTML page, see below:

[footer of HTML template page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVYPb.png)

[Wordpress page/post footer that has the same code but isn't showing the CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHHZj.png)

Comment: i think here you can get the answer: [how to load css in footer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/186065/how-to-load-css-in-the-footer)

Comment: This is probably due to some small difference in the HTML - like a container element / class / ID missing somewhere, that gets used in the selectors that apply the formatting to the footer elements. Use your browser dev tools and check what rule(s) apply the formatting you are missing in the working version, and then check if the DOM structure of the non-working one matches those selectors.